# How to draw a resizable area

Tags: android, canvas, resizable

I would like to make an activity like set avatar in contact android application.
I can resize the selection area by touch to corner (up-left and bottom-right).
How can I implement like that?

Please, give me advices.

### Thank you very much.

Edit:
I want it like this:
[It is like this picture](http://up.meotom.net/Files/460279c7-cbe7-41bc-b89d-0429d3190811/2011/03/11/20110311054146lsxO____help.PNG)

My problem is I don't know how to make event: touch, then drag the selection area.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the crop function you mentioned. It will open the gallery where you can pick an image and select a certain area.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 96); 
intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);

try {
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_REQUEST);
}

catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(OptionenActivity.this)
    .setTitle("Error")
    .setMessage("An error occured")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
}
```

And get the result via `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_REQUEST:
            final Bundle extras = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();

            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap image = extras.getParcelable("data");                    
                Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

You'll get this:

[image: crop image]

Comment: Thank you man. Maybe my question is not clearly. So i edited, and attached a picture to demonstration. Please advices.

Comment: I also added am image. If you don't mind using the built-in method to select an area from an image (crop) you can easily use this way. If you want to write this method on your own you should start with displaying the desired image as background and then putting a rectangle on top. You could use `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)` to detect an touch event.

Answer (score 0):

oweride the onDraw method in a frame layout

now you have 2 options resize the frameLayout or change the size in the ondraw method